# inserting formula and drag down based on other column

Tags: excel, vba

I try to surf the internet and try all the possible answer but still got the 1004 error application or object defined error

here's my code:

```
 Sub Status()
Sheets(1).Range("D6").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'Form Capex HRGA'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'Form Capex HRGA'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'Form Capex IT'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'Form Capex IT'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'Form Capex LDD'!R6C3:R2000C12,4,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'Form Capex LDD'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC3,'Form Capex" & _
        "C3:R2000C12,4,0),VLOOKUP(RC3,'Form Capex NPD'!R6C5:R2000C12,2,0))))))))"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("d6:d" & Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
End Sub
```

the code should insert d6 with formula and fill down based on column C because column C is not always in same amount (sometimes it gets 100 or more or perhaps less) so I insert the code below the formula.

When I try to run it, the formula part always been highlighted. Any idea what my mistake is? please help correct my code

thank you

Comment: One of your sheet references is incomplete.  You have `VLOOKUP(RC3,'Form Capex" & _         "C3:R2000C12,4,0)`

Comment: @chrisneilsen what should the correction be made? and just asking, how do I define sheet name reference? like should I do 'Form' or 'Form" or "Form' or "Form"?

Comment: @chrisneilsen sorry I just combine it with full straight line and it works now the problem move to next part row, the selection autofill, any ideas whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

just found my mistake

1. thanks to Chris (on the comment) that my formula is not complete
2. for the mistake of autofill, I use this code

   lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row

   Sheets(1).Range("D6:S6").Autofill Range("D6:S" & lr)